# jwt expiration check loopholes

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, jwt, token

I have a function to check my JWT expiration in my front-end. 
My token expires every 60min

```
function tokenExpired(token) {
    const expiry = (JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))).exp;
    return (Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1000)) >= expiry;
  }
```

So this function checks my token's expiration time and compares it to my local time.
Now what if I change my local time. Some people like to change their phone time settings to 10-15min faster or slower.
Won't this affect my token expiration?
How can I make this expiration check foolproof? Any better way to do this?

Comment: Its not the client that will write when the token expires. It is "you" the backend doing that and giving it to the client upon first authentication. Their local time setting doesn't matter.

Comment: In my project, the token expiration check is done in the front-end.

Comment: If its client site you cannot defend against people tampering with the code. I can just open dev console and play with code and markup, and my local time for that matter. You can't really stop me. That's why you should not trust any data from the client, unlñess you have encrypted it yourself and made it temper proof, (welcome to JWT). API endpoint to validate tokens wouldn't be half bad.

Comment: the client side check is/should be completely irrelevant. If you use the token for authorization, it's send back to the server with each request and the server should reject it when it is expired, no matter what the client "thinks"

Comment: Every time the API is hit, the token is generated so we wanted to restrict the token generation only if it is expired. Hence the token expiration check was implemented.

Comment: usually you dont generate the token on the api but you just respond with invalid token when its expired. Then the client knows to request a new one.